# How do you break into the debugger from Python source code?

Tags: python, debugging, breakpoints, pdb

What do you insert into Python source code to have it break into pdb (when execution gets to that spot)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

See [Python: Coding in the Debugger for Beginners](http://jjinux.blogspot.com/2007/08/python-coding-in-debugger-for-beginners.html) for this and more helpful hints.

Comment: From [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own programming question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.

Comment: How would that work in an IDE? It doesn't work in Pycharm

Answer (score 15):

As of Python 3.7, you can use `breakpoint()` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint