# Can I call a method and step into it while inside a pdb trace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdb

If i am inside a pdb set_trace() console, I am able to call python methods in real time. It is also possible for me to step into or out of the subsequent method call.

Is it possible for me to combine these features, and call a method and immediately step into it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python debugger: Stepping into a function that you have called interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228642/python-debugger-stepping-into-a-function-that-you-have-called-interactively)

Comment: [`pdb.runcall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.runcall) is probably what you want.