# Multithreaded python application not hitting breakpoints in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, ptvs

I am currently developing a PyQt application in Visual Studio.
Debugging has been working great, until I decided to keep my UI responsive by moving stuff to a worker thread with Qt Threads.

```
class MainWindow(base, form):

    start_work = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Create a seperate thread in which the update information is polled.
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        # Create Worker object and move it to new thread
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # connect signal to start work in the extra tread
        self.start_work.connect(self.worker.get_work_done)
        self.thread.start()

    #function emit a signal to start doing the work
    def do_work(self):
        self.startWork.emit()
```

Any function that is invoked on my worker object is connected via signal slots

```
class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def get_work_done(self):
        #lets do some time consuming work.
```

The code works fine. The only problem is now, I cannot debug anything that is happening inside `get_work_done`. Visual studio won't break at those breakpoints.

When I break inside any `MainWindow` function, the Visual Studio Debugger shows only one thread. It seems unaware of any other threads created by the application.

Answer (score 8):

As said already all threads not created using Python need to be registered with PTVS. To do this for a QThread, call this in the threads run method:

```
import pydevd;pydevd.settrace(suspend=False)
```

Some more info here: [Can I put break points on background threads in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114719/can-i-put-break-points-on-background-threads-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Debugger needs to play some tricks to detect new threads and set up its hooks (which are needed to hit breakpoints etc). It does so by hijacking the standard Python `_thread` module. If you're creating the threads in some way that circumvents that module altogether, which is what I suspect Qt does here, the debugger will not be aware of those threads.

Try using the standard `threading` module instead of `QThread`, and see if that helps.

Comment: If I use the regular threading module, I cannot use the signal and slot mechanism to communicate between the threads. This is why I would like to make use of Qt threading. There is no way to make the debugger aware of those threads?

Comment: Have the same problem in Python for .Net... the thread is created in a .net module somwhere, and calling an event in Python.  Need to be able to force the hooks somehow??

Comment: There's no good generic solution to this, unfortunately, short of trying to support what every specific library does. You can hack the code for the debugger (visualstudio_py_debugger.py) to add such support, and perhaps it could be made extensible to make this easier. Feel free to file all of these on http://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS